# Javascript event handler multiple targets

Tags: javascript

I have javascript event handler for multiple modals on one page.  The goal is to close the box when the user clicks outside modal.

There is a possibility of up to 4 modals on one page, some have 2 and some have 3.  When I have a page with all 4 modals this function works perfectly.  The issue comes when I have only 2 or 3. The function may work for the first box, but will not fire for the 3rd box.

I need this to fire no matter what modals are on the page.

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal || event.target == modal2 || event.target == modal3 || event.target == modal4) {
event.target.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fastgrowingtrees/w3bo9q29/

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle link

Comment: You should debug and check what is coming in event.target when you have 3 modal or provide fiddle where you should keep you three modal on page which will help us to answer you

Comment: Use ids instead of direct objects. Your code fails because you try to compare non-existant objects. Check if the id exists before you get the object.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fastgrowingtrees/w3bo9q29/

Comment: Instead of saving the elements, save the ids.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Very new to javascript, could someone help me out with a bit more info? Maybe an example?

Comment: Try: event.target.getAttribute('id')== 'modal', so you must set ID for DOM

Comment: @JustinFrenchi will suggest you to use this library to handle modal which will do everything what you are trying to do http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ bootstrap modal is best to handle each and everything you do not need to write too much code to handle these thing

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Every time you make or remove a modal, remove its id from the modals array. Since all modals are handled the same, you can just loop through them without having to copy paste the init code again.

The key here is working with the ids, not with the actual elements, since in your original code, when you add or remove a modal, you also have to edit the document.onclick function.

```
   var modals = ["myModal_1", "myModal_2", "myModal_3", "myModal_4"];
    modals.forEach(function( id, index ) {
        var modal = document.getElementById(id),
            btn = document.getElementById('m' + id.slice(3)),
            span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[index];
        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }   
    });
    document.onclick = function(event) {
        if (modals.indexOf(event.target.id) !== -1) {
            event.target.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

set

```
<div id="modal">Modal</div>
...
<div id="modal4">Modal 4</div>
```

check IF Statement like below:

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
var x=event.target.getAttribute("id");
if ( x == 'modal' || x == 'modal2' || x == 'modal3' || x == 'modal4') {
event.target.style.display = "none";
}
}
```